# multi query search form with php

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have a search form that is used to get records based on date entered, it works perfectly, but now I am trying to implement a functionality where I can search from a particular date to another, how  do I go about this.

This is what I have tried

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" action="date_policy.php" method="post" name="form1" id="form1"> 
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label" for="input Date"><span class="asasa">*</span> Date:</label>
<div class="controls">
  <input type="text" name="date" value="" size="32" id="input insured Date" placeholder="e.g 12-5-2014" />

  </div>
</div>

<p align="center">
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-mini btn-primary" value="Search" /></p>
      </form>
```

and my query snippet

```php
mysql_select_db($database_kbl, $kbl);
$query_cert = sprintf("SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE Date = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_cert, "text"));
$cert = mysql_query($query_cert, $kbl) or die(mysql_error());
$row_cert = mysql_fetch_assoc($cert);
$totalRows_cert = mysql_num_rows($cert);
```

Comment: Bro please don't use mysql_* it is deprecated

Comment: you add a second input box and you adjust your sql query to be `Date BETWEEN`

Comment: date between? dont get

Comment: @odumbotolu: [RTFM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between), seriously. And indeed: stop using `mysql_*`. From your code, it would seem that you're learning PHP/MySQL, if so: don't waste time learning the deprecated extensions, [read the red box at the top](http://www.php.net/mysql_connect), and the pages it links to, choose one of the new, better, safer and more powerful extensions instead

Comment: thnks i will check and do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about BETWEEN in your SELECT-Statement? like this:

```
$query_cert = sprintf("SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE Date BETWEEN %s AND %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_cert, "text"), GetSQLValueString($mySecondDateField, "text"));
```

Comment: cool, but mind u the dates am searchin in between are from the same fields,

Answer (score 0):

OK since google isn't your friend clearly.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="date_policy.php" method="post" name="form1" id="form1"> 
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label" for="input Date"><span class="asasa">*</span>Start Date:</label>
<div class="controls">
  <input type="text" name="startdate" value="" size="32" id="input insured Date" placeholder="e.g 12-5-2014" />
  </div>
<label class="control-label" for="input Date"><span class="asasa">*</span>End Date:</label>
<div class="controls">
  <input type="text" name="enddate" value="" size="32" id="input insured Date" placeholder="e.g 12-5-2014" />
  </div>
</div>

<p align="center">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-mini btn-primary" value="Search" /></p>
</form>
```

and the SQL becomes (note I stripped out your parse function as I have no idea how it works)

```
mysql_select_db($database_kbl, $kbl);
$query_cert = "SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE Date BETWEEN '".$_POST['startdate']."' AND '".$_POST['enddate']."' ";
$cert = mysql_query($query_cert, $kbl) or die(mysql_error());
$row_cert = mysql_fetch_assoc($cert);
$totalRows_cert = mysql_num_rows($cert);
```

Comment: Answer with a gaping injection vulnerability... nice

Comment: I'm not fixing all his crappy code to start with he can work that out himself.  I'm just showing him how to use BETWEEN since he fails at google!